# generated asymmetric key in google KMS: Private or Public?

Tags: private-key, encryption-asymmetric, google-cloud-kms

Pretty basic question. When I create a key using google KMS, is that key public or private?

I need to develop an asymmetric key pair using HSM for a project, someone asked me, and I'm not crystal clear on that. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

When you create an asymmetric key using google KMS both the private and public key are created. To retrieve the public key you can use the GetPublicKey API call. https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys.cryptoKeyVersions/getPublicKey

You cannot retrieve the private key from Cloud KMS. You can only access it via API calls for AsymmetricSign or AsymmetricDecrypt.